# Did the real Arturo get left behind?

Tags: sliders

I've been rewatching [Sliders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliders) again, and partway through the second season (episode titled "Post-Traumatic Slide Syndrome", there are two versions of Arturo fighting it out at the end - the original, and the one from the world they are on.  Only one makes it through to slide to the next world, and it's not very clear which is which.  Subsequent episodes seem to treat it like this never happened.

Has it ever been answered which Arturo made it through and which one stayed behind, either in the show, or other media somewhere? The [wikipedia entry for the Arturo character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximillian_Arturo) seems to indicate this question was never resolved.

Comment: If the original was left behind then that would be the base for the show returning I can picture Quinn getting all the other Quinn's to fight the kromags and save wade and all the original characters I heard of a Jerry O'Connell interview mentioning a possible reboot for the show and this was recent

Comment: Another thing to note is benish picking up the blueprints for the atom bomb And the benish from their world who understood where they went when the FBI came to ask about them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Co-creator [**Tracy Tormé**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0868124/) said in [this interview](http://earthprime.com/interviews/tracy-torme-2009.html):

> *For what it’s worth, **I believe the wrong Arturo slid.***

And in the season 3 episode [The Guardian](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0702784/?ref_=ttep_ep4):

> Arturo comments that he has just seen his first American football game. However, the original Arturo seemed like a pretty big American football fan.
>
> Co-creator and writer Tracy Tormeé has hinted **that seeming gaffe was actually a clue inserted to show our Sliders no longer had the Arturo they began with.**

Even though it was never resolved in the series, I'd go with Tracy Tormé's original intention of it being the wrong Arturo.

There was a lot of "bad stuff" going on behind the scenes, from unhappy actors to deliberately ending the series with a cliffhanger *(the production team knew in advance that season 5 would be the last season)*.

Comment: I also second the view that the wrong Arturo slid.  If you look at Arturo's character before and after this episode, you will note that the Arturo that slid was grumpier and more whiny than Arturo was shown to be before this episode.  The Arturo before was more calm in his assessment.  The Artur after seems to be on the verge of losing it every time he speaks --- and seems more hostile to the group.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that link...I had no idea the Powers That Be were so petty about the production.

Answer (score 0):

In season 2 episode 9 titled In Dino Veritas, they are all 4 wearing collars around their neck, the collars shock them if they don't tell the truth. They stated they got them in a previous world, although we don't see that world like many. Anyway i think depending on how you look at it this episode shines evidence on that. The evidence is the collars. Like i said they get shocked if they lie. So the other characters we can assume would have asked him if he was the real one (original) or one from the multiverse. Depending on the collars shocking him or not would have told them. As we all know they don't tell us if they asked him. But then again during the episode when the two professors fight ending with one sliding and one staying, we see a shocked oh no look on the professors face. So this could leave us to believe he was left behind. I think it was meant to be a cliffhanger. Basically left to a open mind and what we want to believe.